# Type Inference Compiler Error In Eclipse with Java8 but not with Java7

Tags: generics, java-8, type-inference, eclipse-luna

The below piece of code doesn't compile in Eclipse Luna with jdk 1.8.0_05. Eclipse compiler says : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to long

It though compiles in Luna with jdk 1.7 and also compiles using jdk 1.8 when invoked from command line. Can anyone help me identify what could be wrong? Eclipse JDK?

The code works in : http://www.tryjava8.com/

```
public class TestJava8Issue {

    public static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = Math.max(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2, 2);
    public static final int KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 60; // seconds

    TestJava8Issue(final int size, final long ttl){
        System.out.println("size: " + size + " " + " ttl: " + ttl);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestJava8Issue(CORE_POOL_SIZE, get(KEEP_ALIVE_TIME));
    }

    public static <T> T get(T value) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Eclipse Java Development Tools
Version: 3.10.0.v20140501-0200
Build id: I20140501-0200

java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: +1, Most likely an interesting case of *target type inference* running mad (i.e. a bug in the Eclipse compiler). Workarounds like `get((long)KEEP_ALIVE_TIME)` are possible, but one could consider filing this as a bug for the eclipse developer team.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440019

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105299/java-8-converting-an-integer-to-a-long-compilation-issue?noredirect=1#comment42717157_27105299